# How to disable WM6.5.3 gestures?

Tags: .net, windows-mobile, compact-framework, gestures, windows-mobile-6.5

I am working on a .NET 2.0 application targetting the WM5 SDK, what is the correct way to disable the gesture functionality when running on a WM6.5.3 device that only affects the forms I am using?

This is causing an issue when I have a signature capture control inside a tab control - when the signature is entered it's quite common for the tab control to switch tabs as WM6.5.3 picks it up as a gesture.

I don't want to disable the gesture functionality device wide, nor can I upgrade the application to target the WM6.5.3 SDK as it still needs to work on older devices.

Cheers

Comment: This question is a possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495315/windows-mobile-6-5-gestures-and-c-2-0-application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used NativeWindow implementation from OpenNetCF to capture and handle the WM_GESTURE on the signature capture controls.